# What is an expression, phrase, or word that describes service being fast?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, compliment

Basically, I want to say this:

> I went to that place for brunch with my girlfriend last weekend, the service was **pretty fast**, and the food was good too.

I want to say that the service was good in that it was pretty fast, without a delay, etc.

Comment: You can say *fast* or *prompt* which means 'without delay'.

Comment: Your original sentence is perfectly fine. Why do you need a different word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synonyms I can think of for "fast" in similar context:

*The service was*:

- expeditious
- prompt
- attentive

Comment: I think unless it was a facetious usage, *expeditious* would be a bit "flowery" to use in a sentence that also includes the word *brunch*.

Comment: Why are you serving as a thesaurus rather than telling the OP to look at one?

Comment: Because a Q&A site to which the answer is always "look it up elsewhere" is neither helpful nor friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I typically hear the phrase *timely* for service:

> They have excellent food and timely service.

Comment: I think "timely" has more conotations with "serendipity", and is more often used in contexts where something "just happens to happen" at exactly the optimum time. You might even perhaps say it about *slow* delivery of food if that gave you more time for a pre-prandial aperitif, and you valued that. In an eaterie with OP's context I think "prompt" is far more appropriate.

Comment: @Fumble: _Timely_ is used this way where I live and where I grew up. So... regardless of connotations, my suggestion is accurate. See also: _timeliness_, which we use to refer to someone's ability to always be on time.

Comment: Perhaps it's a regional thing. To me, someone's *timeliness* might easily suggest an (uncanny?) ability to exercise "appropriate timing", which might not be the same thing as their *punctuality*.

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms for "pretty fast":

- Quick
- Prompt
- Speedy

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the service was ***swift***.

Answer (score 0):

***Lightning Service*** should please the waiter, steward, bartender, manager or whoever served you.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not for food service, but the first phrase I can think of to describe fast is "blink of an eye".